# Submit a form with data using a custom React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I want to create a hook that's called to submit a form using fetch.

This is what I have right now. The component holding the form:

```
const MyForm = (): ReactElement => {
    const [status, data] = useSubmitForm('https://myurl-me/', someData);
    
    return <>
        <div className='Feedback-form'>
            <div className='body'>
                <form>
                    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='name' required />
                    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='email' required />
                    <button className='submit-feedback-button' type='button'>Send feedback</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
}
```

The custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useSubmitForm = (url: string, data: URLSearchParams): [string, []] => {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>('idle');
    const [responseData, setData] = useState<[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!url) return;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setStatus('fetching');

            const response = await fetch(url, {      
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'text/html',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: data
            });

            const data = await response.json();

            setData(data);
            setStatus('fetched');
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    return [status, responseData];
};

export default useSubmitForm;
```

My problem is that I think this hook is being called right away. How do I make this hook and call it in such a way that it's only called when the form is submitted and all the data I need to send in the request body is there to be included?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, the effect runs once when the component mounts and since `url` is truthy, it skips the early return and invokes `fetchData`.

> How do I make this hook and call it in such a way that it's only
> called when the form is submitted and all the data I need to send in
> the request body is there to be included?

You need to also return a function for the component to invoke and pass along the form field values. I think you've a couple basic options.

1. Convert the form fields to be controlled inputs and store the field state in the component and invoke a "fetch" function returned from the `useSubmitForm` hook.
2. Return an `onSubmit` handler from the `useSubmitForm` to attach to your `form` element. The `onSubmit` handler would need to know what fields to access from the `onSubmit` event though, so passing an array of field names to the hook (i.e. a "config") makes sense.

## Solution 1 - Use controlled inputs and returned fetch function

Unwrap the `fetchData` function from the `useEffect` hook and add a form field data parameter to it. Since `fetch` and `response.json()` can both throw errors/rejections you should surround this block in a try/catch. Return the custom `fetchData` function for the form to invoke.

useSubmitForm

```
const useSubmitForm = (
  url: string,
  data: URLSearchParams
): [function, string, []] => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("idle");
  const [responseData, setData] = useState<[]>([]);

  const fetchData = async (formData) => {
    setStatus("fetching");

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "text/html",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      setData(data);
      setStatus("fetched");
    } catch (err) {
      setData(err);
      setStatus("failed");
    }
  };

  return [fetchData, status, responseData];
};
```

MyForm

```
const MyForm = (): ReactElement => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({ // <-- create field state
    email: '',
    username: '',
  });
  const [fetchData, status, data] = useSubmitForm(
    "https://myurl-me/",
    someData
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // handle successful/failed fetch status and data/error
  }, [status, data]);

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFields((fields) => ({
      ...fields,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData(fields); // <-- invoke hook fetchData function
  };

  return (
    <div className="Feedback-form">
      <div className="body">
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}> // <-- attach submit handler
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            placeholder="name"
            onChange={changeHandler} // <-- attach change handler
            value={fields.username}  // <-- pass state
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email"
            onChange={changeHandler}  // <-- attach change handler
            value={fields.email}  // <-- attach state
          />
          <button className="submit-feedback-button" type="submit">
            Send feedback
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Solution 2 - Return an `onSubmit` handler and pass an array of fields to the `useSubmitForm`

useSubmitForm

```
const useSubmitForm = (
  url: string,
  data: URLSearchParams,
  fields: string[],
): [function, string, []] => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("idle");
  const [responseData, setData] = useState<[]>([]);

  const fetchData = async (formData) => {
    setStatus("fetching");

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "text/html",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      setData(data);
      setStatus("fetched");
    } catch (err) {
      setData(err);
      setStatus("failed");
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = fields.reduce((formData, field) => ({
      ...formData,
      [field]: e.target[field].value,
    }), {});
    fetchData(formData);
  }

  return [onSubmit, status, responseData];
};
```

MyForm

```
const MyForm = (): ReactElement => {
  const [onSubmit, status, data] = useSubmitForm(
    "https://myurl-me/",
    someData,
    ['email', 'username'] // <-- pass field array
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // handle successful/failed fetch status and data/error
  }, [status, data]);

  return (
    <div className="Feedback-form">
      <div className="body">
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}> // <-- attach submit handler
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            placeholder="name"
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email"
          />
          <button className="submit-feedback-button" type="submit">
            Send feedback
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit submit-a-form-with-data-using-a-custom-react-hook]

In my opinion the second solution is the cleaner solution and requires less on consuming components to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, I went with your second solution. One question though. I understand what useEffect is used for (and you describe it in your post), however, what exactly should I be doing in useEffect() to handle successful/failed fetch status and data/error? Could you give a small example?

Comment: @erol_smsr Sure, many times when processing form data you want to do certain things *after* a successful or failed submission. For example, if the form submission failed then you may want to display an error message to the user, or if successful notify the user with a toast and navigate to another page.

Comment: @DrewReese Hello, I went with solution 1. I do have trouble mocking the inner function - fetchData. I did something like:

`import * as useSubmitForm from './useSubmitForm';
const useSubmitFormSpy = jest.spyOn(
    useSubmitForm,
    'useSubmitForm'
  ) as jest.SpyInstance;

  useSubmitFormsSpy.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
    fetchData: jest.fn(() =>
      Promise.resolve(mock)
    ),
  }));`

Although its not working properly. any suggestions on to improve it?

Comment: Also, what do I write on the expect statement?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Since your question is a bit off-topic for this post it would likely be more beneficial to you to create a new post on SO with accompanying [mcve] and details. If you do make a new post feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.